# Change or add element into the Traccar app

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

Traccar app is using Extjs/javascript and I am trying to add some div element into the app UI.
This is my traccar server UI in the right corner it has four div elements by default:
https://ibb.co/0yZXvVV

and in this UI the owner add two more div elements into the UI, the element that I want to add into my UI is in the picture it is rounded in red:
https://ibb.co/HBbz7hj

If you need to inspect some code ,here is the access to the demo login:
http://acesso.rastreieaqui.com.br/index.html
username: demo,
password: demo

and this is the code of that div element :

```
<a class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" role="button" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" id="button-1078" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false" data-componentid="button-1078" style="right: auto; left: 1028px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <span id="button-1078-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-toolbar-small ">
        <span id="button-1078-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-toolbar-small  x-btn-no-text x-btn-icon x-btn-icon-left x-btn-button-center ">
            <span id="button-1078-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small  x-btn-glyph" style="font-family:FontAwesome;"></span>
            <span id="button-1078-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-toolbar-small">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

and I only have one html file in the web folder but when I add this element in that html file there is no change. So how can I add this element into my traccar UI , do I need to edit extjs and how can I do that or I can just add this code element somewhere ? 
This is the html file that I have :

````
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>traccar</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg-banner" id="bg-bn"></div>




<div id="attribution">Powered by <a href="traccar">GPS Tracking System</a></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="lib/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>

<script id="loadScript" src="load.js"></script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new button to the map panel, you need to edit `Map.js` file:

https://github.com/traccar/traccar-web/blob/master/web/app/view/map/Map.js

Make sure that you compile source after or use debug version of the app.